# registered wrong language with joomla

Tags: joomla

When I registered I clicked English (UK) instead of default.  I realize that was probably a mistake.  When I went to download it automatically says English (UK)  I am in California.
I tried to register with another email address but it did not give me the language default choice.  How can I change this or is it ok to download the English (UK) version.
Please leave detailed hot to instructions.  Because I am new to all of this.  Thanks, Cheryl

Answer (score 0):

Log in. Go to this address and you will be able to change language:

http://**your.website.com**/index.php?option=com_user&view=user&layout=form

Remember to replace your.website.com with actual address of your website!